# activate/deactivate javascript on button click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, css

I am using a javascript to zoom an image on my asp.net web page. I want to put 2 buttons on it like "Zoom" "Cancel Zoom" and accordingly activate/deactivate  the javascript functionality. Right now I have a css class on which the javascript operated to produces the zoom effect. The image is like:

```
<a id="big" href="source of image" class"classforzoom">     
    <img id="small" src="some small image on page" />
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
           //some code here
        };

        $(".jqzoom").jqzoom(options);

    });
</script>
```

How do I programmatically do this on the onClick events on the 2 buttons?

This is what I am using in the head tag of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Related toggleclass() method:

```
toggleClass: function(F,E) {
    if(typeof E!=="boolean") {
        E = !o.className.has(this,F)
    }
    o.className[E?"add":"remove"](this,F)
}
```

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using?

Comment: I do not much about jquery but this is included in the header of my page:                                                                   `<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"`>
    </script>

Comment: That is just the plain jQuery library. Where did you get the code above with the **"$(".zoom").zoom(options);** part? That is not standard jQuery.

Comment: Also, it's really unclear what you are asking. What exactly is the front-end supposed to look like? And what "buttons" are you referring to (the code you supplied has no buttons).

Comment: its called jqzoom. sorry for the typo..anyways that not the point as it works perfect..I just want to be able to control its working with a button in my c# code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deactivate**

```
$("a#cancelzoom").click(function(event)
{
     $('.classforzoom').unbind();
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Activate**

```
$("a#zoom").click(function(event)
{
    $('.classforzoom').jqzoom(options);
    $('.classforzoom').bind();        
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the jQuery [click method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and then use the [unbind method](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove an event from an object?

Answer (score 0):

Also since you say you are using a css class for the zoom effect check out the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

Comment: Since i do not understand any of jquery, I am pasting the function content from the query in my main question. thanks